# How to pass multiple lists in JPQL Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I have table like this

```
VID   CID RID
101   151  BE
114   154  BE
114   155  BE
115   17   LU
115   151  BE
115   155  BE
113   156  BE
113   166  BE
```

If the user passes 151 BE as input I need to pass only 101,
If the user passes 154 BE and 155 BE as input i need to pass only 114

The input 151 BE or 154 BE and 155 BE I will pass it using a List.

So what is the most effective way to achieve this in java or oracle?

Is there any specific way in java to achieve this ?

Comment: JPQL relies on JPA entities. You quote neither a JPA entity nor JPQL query. No idea what this "question" is

Comment: i guess you mean sth like `select top 1 vid from TABLE where cid=? anc rid=? order by vid asc`? i didnt understand the question

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking, give lists of conditions how to return the matching VID:

if this is your entity:

```
class Entity
{

    private VID vid;
    private RID rid;
    private CID cid;


    public Entity()
    {

    }



    //the proper getter and setters


}
```

This is how I would build a query given the Conditions:

```
//private List<VID> getCommonVID(CID[] cids, RID[] rids) -- could also use an array
private List<VID> getCommonVID(List<CID> cids, List<RID> rids)
{

    String sql = "";
    sql += "SELECT entity.VID FROM TABLE";
        + "WHERE ";

    int cnt = 0;
    int max = rids.length;


    //build sql String
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        String op = (cnt == 0)? "":" AND ";
        sql += op +  "Entity.CID = :" + String.valueOf(cids.get(i));
        sql += " AND " + "Entity.RID = :" + String.valueOf(rids.get(i));
    }

    Query q = new Query(sql);


    for(int i = 0; i<max; i++)
    {
        q.setParameter(String,valueOf(cids.get(i)), cids.get(i))
        q.setParameter(String,valueOf(rids.get(i)), rids.get(i))
    }

    List<VID> vids = q.getResultList();

    if(vids.size() < 1) return new ArrayList();
    else return vids;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think in your case (you dont have a lot of rows to inser )use java.in commons use directly dabaseserver when we want to insert huge number of rows(migration for exemple...).